# Making the architecture library of models in 3ds max

Tags: 3d-modeling, 3ds-max

I am learning 3ds max with respect to architecture building design. Its my first week of course.

I just wanted to is it possible that i can collect various small models of
furnitures , utensils , household things , office things and make a complete library so that when i make empty buildings then i just browse through my catalogue and add things in my building.

Is there any plugin or software which do that by just browse and click.

or i have to do manual work as well like chnaging size , resolution.

My main aim is to have design the building , with models and furniture.

i wanted to , how does the main companies doing that manages with models or work